# asp.net google charts problems my project

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, charts, webmethod

this code does not work. what should i do please help me there is no problem in database i couldn't find the solution

Is there a problem with WebMethod? I did everything but there is something I can't see

I'm stuck on this, my project is waiting for this

I will be very grateful to the friend who solved this

[WebMethod]

```
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]


public static List<ChartDetails> GetPiechartData()
{

    List<ChartDetails> dataList = new List<ChartDetails>();

    string sConnString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=deneme;Integrated Security=True";


    SqlConnection baglanti = new SqlConnection(sConnString);

    
        

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select begeni , kontrolid from yorum", baglanti);

        baglanti.Open();

        SqlDataReader droku = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (droku.Read())
        {
            dataList.Add(new ChartDetails
            {
                kontrolid = droku["kontrolid"].ToString(),
                begeni = Convert.ToInt32(droku["begeni"]),



            });

        }

        return dataList;
    }

public class ChartDetails
{
    public string kontrolid { get; set; }
    public int begeni { get; set; }
}
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', { packages: ['corechart'] });
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">


    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "Default17.aspx/GetPiechartData",
            data: "{}",
            success: function (response) {                    
                drawchart(response.d);
            },

            error: function () {
                alert("Error loading data...........");
            }
        });
    })

  

    function drawchart(dataValues) {

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(); 

        data.addColumn('string', 'kontrolid');
        data.addColumn('number', 'begeni');

        for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
            data.addRow([dataValues[i].kontrolid, dataValues[i].begeni]);
        }

        var options = {
            title: 'Company Performance',
            curveType: 'function',
            legend: { position: 'bottom' }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curvechart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
    }


</script>
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific about what you're trying to achieve and what error are you stuck with ?

Comment: hello i will use google charts and i get error Error loading data..charts not working at all